# sigma.js: is there a way to drag-select multiple nodes?

Tags: sigma.js

I try to do a drag-select but end up dragging the graph itself. I don't see any settings that can change the drag action.

Is there a way to drag-select multiple nodes at once?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see this example: https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/wiki/How-to-select-and-drag-multiple-nodes

with this plugin: https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes

[Linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js) provides high-level plugins to Sigma.js. It is free for open source projects.

*Disclaimer:* I work at Linkurious SAS.

Comment: Have you ended the project? So, isn't possible anymore to drag one or multiple one of sigma.js which is exported from gephi?

Answer (score -1):

here you go, a plugin that i made for multiple selection of nodes by drag-selecting them

https://gist.github.com/deanshub/2ee8d3aee5f325c8c4aa

you should add the file provided to your html like so: (or use something like [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/))

```
<script src="sigma.plugins.nodesSelection.js"></script>
```

To use the plugin you should activate it and give a callback

```
sigma.plugins.activateMouseEvents(s,function(err, selectedNodes){
    console.log(selectedNodes);
});
```

Comment: In case anyone's still looking to achieve this in 2017 or beyond, I was able to get the above plugin to work but only using the "canvas" renderer. If you use the current sigma.js, you'll use WebGL by default so you need to explicitly initiate the graph using canvas (https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Renderers#the-default-renderer). Follow up, if you're using the json parser like me, you'll need to use the 'update' rather than 'create' syntax (bottom of https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.parsers.json)